# I am trying to make my bot be able to respond to a command that starts with a certain set of characters instead of having an exact command

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make my bot be able to respond to a command that starts with a certain set of characters instead of having an exact command. I figured out how to use it with client.event but I can't figure out how to do it using client.command.

As an example let's say I want it to send a message that says "Hello!" when the command ".hi" is sent. I want it to work even if a user sends ".hii" or maybe ".hi!". I can get this to work by using the startswith command. Below is my working client.event code and my broken client.command code:

client.event code:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.lower().startswith('.hi'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

client.command code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', case_insensitive=True)

@client.command()
async def hi(message):
  if message.content.startswith('hi'):
    print('Hello!')
```

Comment: You seem to assume that your `commands.Bot` statement will strip the `.` prefix from the command text before it reaches the `hi` function, and that it will somehow make any string comparisons within the function automatically case-insensitive. Are those true assumptions? In particular, I don't know how the second one could be true, since `startswith` is a Python builtin, and not part of discord.py. Try replacing the `if` line in your command with a copy of the `if` line from your event, since your event code does not make those assumptions.

Comment: If something like the above doesn't work, please edit your post to say how the command version is "broken", and how you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the command, you could specify the aliases of the command like this:

```
@client.command(aliases=['hii', 'hi!'])
async def hi(ctx):
    print('Hello!')
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=aliases#discord.ext.commands.Command.aliases

Also your command is broken because you need to pass in `ctx` as a parameter for a command, not `message`.

Comment: Thank you yes I could do that but it would make the code quite longer. I was looking for a possibly shorter solution

Answer (score 0):

Your `@client.command()` won't work because you never passed in `ctx`, by the way, to send a message you might want to use `await ctx.send("Hello!")`.
The "full command" would look something like this, **though its not really what you want as you would have to type** `.hi hi`

```py
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx, message):
    if message.startswith('hi'):
        await ctx.send('Hello!')
```

If you **actually** want to do that you should try using your `@client.event` (with on_message, basically the one you already have) as I dont think that you can do that unless you **use aliases** *(Which is not a good option though)*:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['hi!', 'hiiiiii', 'hello'])
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello!')
```

In conclusion, if you really want to do something like this, use your exsistent `@client.event` with `on_message`

*(Just as @moinierer3000 said)*

Comment: Np! If it helped out mark the response as accepted :D